# passing java.util.List variable between 2 jsp files

Tags: jsp

i am writing 2 jsp files(file1.jsp,file2.jsp). In file1.jsp i am retrieving some names from database and storing them in an ArrayList names 'names'. Now i want to pass that ArrayList to file2.jsp.

```
/*file1.jsp*/
            //some jsp code 
List names = new ArrayList();
names.add(namesFromDatabase);   //assume 5 names are added.

/*file2.jsp*/
            //here i want print size of ArrayList 'names'
names.size();
            //also i want to print 3rd name from the list.
names.get(2);
```

Can anyone help me in finding solution for my problem.
regards.

Comment: You should really be using Servlets. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files

Comment: Not really, this has nothing to do with using Servlets.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the `names` variable session scoped. Here are the [docs](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/11/syntaxref11.fm14.html)

Answer (score 0):

Make your second jsp file a tagfile. Tagfiles can accept parameters, so it works similar to a function call.